# Putting .NET and Classic ASP Code within an SSL site on a Windows 2k3 server

Tags: .net, asp-classic

I want to invoke some .NET webservices from a classic asp app on 64-bit win2k3 server. The classic code is its own site with SSL set up. Where do I put the .NET code? Do I make a virtual dir off the Classic site?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create a virtual directory, it creates an "application" process thread in the app pool. The site in IIS will also need configuring for asp.net, there's a tab for that in the sites properties.

Ensure the .net web service web.config file is also in the virtual directory.

If the Application Pool also gets used by another site using a different version of .net (ie, v1 with v2) you will encounter problems, so if that's the case create a dedicated application pool for that site in IIS.